# I didn't get required input and output on Azure Cognitive services

Tags: javascript, html, json, azure, azure-cognitive-services

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/linguistics/v1.0/analyzers?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","fa5a4445a080414d95610f74fa3e5626");
            },
            type: "GET",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Documentation Help**

> https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56ea598f778daf01942505ff/operations/56ea59bfca73071fd4b102ba

**input json is below**

```
 {  "language" : "en",  "analyzerIds" : ["4fa79af1-f22c-408d-98bb-b7d7aeef7f04", "22a6b758-420f-4745-8a3c-46835a67c0d2"],   "text" : "Hi, Tom! How are you today?" }
```

**required output is below json**

```
[
    {
        "analyzerId" : "4fa79af1-f22c-408d-98bb-b7d7aeef7f04", 
        "result" : ["NNP",",","NNP","VBP","PRP","NN","."]
    },
    {
        "analyzerId" : "22a6b758-420f-4745-8a3c-46835a67c0d2", 
        "result" : ["(TOP (S (NNP Hi) (, ,) (NNP Tom) (. !)))","(TOP (SBARQ (WHADVP (WRB How)) (SQ (VP (VBP are)) (NP (PRP you)) (NN today) (. ?))))"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're mixing up the 'List Analyzers' and 'Analyze Text' calls.  Your input/output combination suggests you want the latter.  If so, the code should be roughly as follows:

```
    var request = {
        "language": "en",
        "analyzerIds": [
            "4fa79af1-f22c-408d-98bb-b7d7aeef7f04",
            "22a6b758-420f-4745-8a3c-46835a67c0d2"
        ], 
        "text": "Hi, Tom! How are you today?"
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/linguistics/v1.0/analyze?" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","fa5a4445a080414d95610f74fa3e5626");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: JSON.stringify(request),
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
```

The four differences are:

- The URL is `/analyze`, not `/analyzers`
- The `type` is `POST`, not `GET`
- The `Content-Type` needs to be specified
- The `data` object needs to contain the request JSON.